# Does "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" indicate memory leak?

Tags: java

I am learning more about memory leaks and was trying below code:

I have below code which throws `Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"`

```
import com.learn.general.memoryleaks.LeakFactory.Leak;

public class InnerClassMemoryLeakTest {
    static Leak[] leaks = new Leak[100000];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < leaks.length; i++) {
                leaks[i] = new LeakFactory().getLeak();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createLeak() {
        while(true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < leaks.length; i++) {
                leaks[i] = new LeakFactory().getLeak();
            }
        }
    }
}


import java.util.Calendar;

public class LeakFactory {

    double d = Math.random();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    public Leak getLeak(){
        return new Leak();
    }

    public class Leak{
        double d_i = Math.random();
        Calendar calendar_i = Calendar.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Then I have below code which throws `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListMemoryLeak {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> calendars = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        while(true){
            calendars.add(Calendar.getInstance());
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** Does the error in first case indicates that there is a memory leak while in second case it is not?

Comment: How do you define "memory leak"? Who's calling `createLeak()`? Where is the `Leak` class?

Comment: This code is all over the place...

Comment: @shmosel see Matt's answer

Comment: Both classes create a lot of objects and put them in a data structure that won't be collected.  Whether these are memory leaks or not is a matter of your code's *intentions* and/or your *knowledge* that this is happening.  They both look deliberate to me, so I would call neither "leaks".

Comment: @StephenC I am trying to learn about memory leak so what I am doing is intended .... I am looking for explaination about both cases and whether first case indicates memory leak and second case do not ... My understanding is that first case is a memory leak because inner classes holds reference of enclosing class, so even though `LeakFactory` could have been GC'ed but they will not because of inner class reference. Am I right? Look forward if you would throw more concepts ...

Comment: No.  You are not correct. It is largely intentions that determine whether you classify an "excessive" or "fatal" over-use of memory as a leak or not.  There is no technical definition of a memory leak.

Comment: In addition, you seem to be asking whether the `OutOfMemoryError` indicates a leak or not.  No it doesn't do either.  It indicates the **possibility** of a memory leak.   But there can be an OOME without a memory leak ... and *vice versa*.  Read @Makoto's answer.

Comment: *"My understanding is that first case is a memory leak because inner classes holds reference of enclosing class, so even though LeakFactory could have been GC'ed but they will not because of inner class reference."* - Yes ... but since you did it intentionally, you could argue that is not a memory leak.  And for all we know, the outer class could actually be needed ... in real world code.   And you could also argue that the cause of the leak (if we call it a leak) is putting the 100,000 `Leak` objects into a `static` array, and the `LeakFactory` objects just *magnify* the leak.

Comment: Note: that there is a parallel between this "is it a leak or not" argument and the classical theological debate over ["How many angels can dance on the head of a pin"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_many_angels_can_dance_on_the_head_of_a_pin%3F).  Both are pointless (unlike the pin itself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I am trying to learn about memory leak so what I am doing is intended
>   .... I am looking for explaination about both cases and whether first
>   case indicates memory leak and second case do not

In simple words both the errors indicate that JVM is running out of memory, now whether JVM is running out of memory because of memory leak or not is different matter.

Now, coming to your first case - yes, there is a memory leak (deliberate though) because inner classes holds reference of enclosing class so objects created using `new LeakFactory()` were eligible for GC but they were not GC'ed because `Leak` inner class holds a strong reference to them.

To see this more clearly change your `public class Leak{` to `public static class Leak{` and you will notice that JVM will run a little longer and OOM will come few seconds later as compared to your original non-static `Leak` inner class.

Answer (score 1):

A memory leak is the result of a programmer *unintentionally* keeping hold of memory for longer than they should, with such unintentional memory use slowly building up until there isn't any allocatable memory left.

In Java, leaking memory is *tough* to do given the nature of garbage collection and how it actually does look to see how strongly (or weakly) referenced an object is.

Given that you have to *intentionally* spin up all of those classes yourself, there's no argument to make about a leak; you're *intentionally* doing this.  You've created enough references such that you're exhausting your own memory limits.

Memory leaks in Java typically manifest themselves in a sneakier way than that; some reference is kept in a `finalize()` method which doesn't get released until the class is actually garbage collected, and only the VM knows when that actually happens (it could be never).  Thankfully [that method is going away Soon™](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--), so the likelihood of seeing leaks using *that* is at least a little bit reduced.

You could also be *incredibly* evil and do [`Unsafe` things with the language](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/direct-memory-access-in-java/), but that is enough of a red flag that most sensible IDEs and tool sets will warn you of this usage before it becomes the case that you have a major memory leak on your hands.

All of that to say...no.  The exception you see is indicative of you running out of memory.  It is not *directly* indicative of a memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

Too many objects are having their reference lost and are therefore being garbage collected. By default JVM hates if more than 98% or so of the processing of your program is devoted to your objects being thrown away(memory being recycled). You can either repurpose your objects(directly recycle them yourself by making them mutable and reassigning them a new purpose) or you can disable the notification that poses as an error by adding -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to the command line. I have run into this problem when myself a couple times when doing massive amounts of genetic algorithms in which many children are created from the parents and then you kill off most of the least fit children before the next loop of reproducing. Basically you are creating more trash than Java would prefer, even though you probably haven't actually done anything wrong. Just add -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to your command line arguments and see if it ever happens again. to find out where to add it if you are using eclipse, follow these instructions http://www.planetofbits.com/eclipse/increase-jvm-heap-size-in-eclipse/ but put this line instead -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit